# Submit form without opening browser in Windows 8

Tags: html, forms, submit, winjs

I'm building an app using Microsoft's new HTMl5 framework for Metro apps. I've created a form that I use to submit GET data. The problem is, clicking the "Run Query" (Submit) button on the app opens a browser window. What are some ways that I can submit the data in the GET method without opening a browser window.

I've tried using jQuery to do so but with little yield. It throws the message "jQuery" is not defined.

Is there any HTML I can use, or, better yet, something I can add into default.js?

As requested, jQuery I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('.ajaxform').submit(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            for (var id in data) {
                jQuery('#' + id).html(data[id]);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: You want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from your form, save it in an object, encode it using javascript function and use xhr,

Get form values using js, say

```
    var b=document.getElementById(textboxname).value;
    var params={
    parameter:b,
    }
```

In order to encode your parameters you can use the following javascript function,

```
  function formatParams(y) {
    var queryStr = "";

    for (var propertyName in y) {
        var val = y[propertyName];
        queryStr += propertyName + "=" + encodeURI(val) + "&";
    }

    return queryStr.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Call your web service using WinJS.xhr

```
    WinJS.xhr({
        type: "get/post",
        url: "your URL",
        data: formatParams(params),
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    }).done(function (response) {
        var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

       //process accordingly
        }
```

Im assuming you are getting JSON response from your web service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here you are referring to an external script for jQuery.
Since winjs is running under different security restrictions than a typical web app in a browser your scripts must be local.

Since you are already using jquery - assuming version 2.0 or greater which is Win8/winjs compatible - make sure you have included a reference to jquery LOCALLY in your project and NOT from an external website, you can just use $(document) instead of jQuery(document).

ie:
<script src="/scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js" />  (or whatever your version is)
and make sure you have the files locally. You can just go in *Visual Studio to Tools->Library Package Manager->Package Manager Console* and type in 
**install-package jquery**